# How to add a comment on root level in Nuxt 3?

Tags: html, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I want to set a comment like this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- my comment -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head
```

### Context

I want to have a comment on the root level when users inspecting the page via `view page source`.

I'm currently using `ssr: false` in my nuxt.config.ts

### Question

Is it possible to write a custom comment inside the nuxt.config.ts file or anywhere else that would be visible on the root level when inspecting?